# Why does the RecordId get reflected in Name field instead of the Name?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-field

I have created a custom object as XYZ and a created a Visualforce page based on the custom object. When I give the values in the vf page and save them.The record gets created, but in name field the record id is getting reflected.  Can any one help me out?  I shall appreciate your help.

```
<apex:page standardController=" XYZ __c"  sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
 <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
  <apex:commandButton value="SAVE" action="{!SAVE}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="SAVE&MORE" action="{!SAVE}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="CANCEL" action="{!CANCEL}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageblockSection title="Schedule"> 
 <apex:inputField value="{! XYZ __c.ProductPartNumbers__c}" label="Product"/>  
  <apex:inputField value="{! XYZ _c.PricingRequestsQuarterNos__c}" label="Quarter"/> 
  <apex:inputField value="{! XYZ __c.Quantity__c}"/> 
  <apex:inputField value="{! XYZ __c.Price__c}"/>
</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens if the Name field is Text type, and you don't actually enter a name for the object. And looking at your code, there is indeed no input field for `XYZ__c.Name`.